# Should I create a column for specific behavior?

Tags: database-design

I would like to expose a problem I often have when I work with database and I never knows what to do.

I need to load data from a file into a table (table1) line by line with the help of a software. The file can be a csv or something similar. During the loading I also check the validity each line and each value in this line. If something is wrong I put a message another table (table2) with a reference to my line. A line can have more than one error.

So in my table1 I can have valid and invalid line. To check if a line is valid or not I need to check if there is a message, a line, in my table2. I hope this is clear.

My question now. Thinking about database design should I create a column valid (true/false) in my table one to avoid the have to check table2 each time I want to get value from table one.

Example:

```
table1:
reference | version | var1 | var2 | var3
----------------------------------------
 001      | 1       | x    | y    | z
 001      | 1       | a    | b    | c
 001      | 2       | null | y    | z
 001      | 2       | null | t    | u
 001      | 3       | x    | y    | z
 001      | 3       | a    | b    | c
 001      | 4       | null | y    | null
 001      | 4       | null | t    | null


table2:
reference | version | message
------------------------------------------
 001      | 2       | var1 cannot be null
 001      | 4       | var1 cannot be null
 001      | 4       | var3 cannot be null
```

In table1 I have an item 001 with 4 versions. Version 4 is not valid. This information of validity come from table2.

I always need to be able to request the latest valid reference. Get the last valid reference. To do so I need the check into 2 tables.

Check last line of table1 then compare it with table2. If invalid ignore last invalid line then repeat the request. This seems so heavy...

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, what you might consider doing is having 3 tables. Table1 would be your "Line" table. You'd have a table, maybe called "Errors," containing the possible types of errors that could exist. Then you'd have a table joining them together, maybe called "LineErrors," which would reference the line, and the type of error it had.

In this case, you could also include a column in your Line table which held a bit value indicating if that line had at least 1 error, which you could determine by looking that line number's primary key up in the LineError table.

Hopefully this makes sense, and that I'm understanding your problem sufficiently.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be applicable to your situation, but I would aim for something like:

```
create table table1
( reference char(3) not null
, version int not null
, var1 ... not null
, var2 ... not null
, var3 ... not null
,   primary key (...) );

create table table1_errors
( reference char(3) not null
, version int not null
, var1 ... 
, var2 ... 
, var3 ...
, time_of_error timestamp not null
, error_message varchar(...) not null )
,     primary key (...));
```

I.e. only correct rows are added in table1, and if possible all validations are enforced by the table.

Rows with errors are added to a separate error table with additional info.

When an error is fixed the row can be moved from the error table to the correct table.